# <tr> dropdown issue in dynamic table. html / php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a drop-down table row beneath another one in a semi auto-generated table. I searched for a bit and learned that you could not animate table elements directly. I tried wrapping my table in a div and the animation worked.

My problem now is that I don't really know how to proceed to make my table with that div while looping on a specific part. It just messes up the table, some way or another.

```
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

           // HEAD OF TABLE //

        </tr>

        {{FOREACH}}
        <tr>

        // ALWAYS VISIBLE TR //

        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden hideable{{$i.id}}">

        //CONTENTS//

        </tr>
        {{/FOREACH}}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tar = $('.hideable'+$(this).attr('attrib_target'));
    tar.slideToggle('slow');
    // tar.toggle();
});
});
```

Where should I open and close the div to have something functional?

EDIT: What I need is basically:

Table header (fixed)

Table Row with basic information (fixed)

Table Row hidden with more info (togglable)

The problem I have is the loop because I need to wrap the hidden table row inside a div AND a table (otherwise, the div is just ejected from the table because of their property). the loop keeps messing with my different attemps at doing it right to be able to animate the hidden part.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If you wrapped the table in a div and it worked what is the problem?

Comment: There is not enought code to post a sure answer... But try to `console log($(this).attr('attrib_target'));`, in the click handler, to see if you at least get the right id value.

Comment: I can get the right id, no problem. the only thing I have trouble with is the animation. i don't know where to open and close the div so i can get a clean table inside a div for the hideable part.

Answer (score 1):

Any part of table elements, be it `<tr>` or `<tbody>` do not hide the overflowing content if the set height is less than the actual height of the contents. That's why the animations don't work with table elements. I would advise to wrapping your content inside a `<div>` and using slideToggle to animate.

Please check the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tar = $('.hideable' + $(this).attr('data-target'));
    tar.slideToggle('slow');
    // tar.toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        // HEAD OF TABLE //
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <!-- {{FOREACH}} -->
  <!-- FOREACH ITERATION 1 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        // ALWAYS VISIBLE TR //
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-target="1">Show</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="hidden hideable1">
        //CONTENTS//
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <!-- END: FOREACH ITERATION 1 -->
  <!-- FOREACH ITERATION 2 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        // ALWAYS VISIBLE TR //
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-target="2">Show</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td>
        <div class="hidden hideable2">
        //CONTENTS//
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <!-- END: FOREACH ITERATION 2 -->
  <!-- {{/FOREACH}} -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```